# Crash xamarin app at start up, Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/datatransport/runtime/dagger/internal/Factory;

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, dagger

**Here is the crash log:**

2021-11-09 14:09:39.214 30577-30577/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.bosch.smartcamera.test, PID: 30577 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/datatransport/runtime/dagger/internal/Factory; at com.google.android.datatransport.runtime.DaggerTransportRuntimeComponent.builder(DaggerTransportRuntimeComponent.java:70) at com.google.android.datatransport.runtime.TransportRuntime.initialize(TransportRuntime.java:76) at com.google.firebase.datatransport.TransportRegistrar.lambda$getComponents$0(TransportRegistrar.java:37) at com.google.firebase.datatransport.-$$Lambda$TransportRegistrar$cPZPPfWZLxVwhtSgzJNU9TpSidE.create(Unknown Source:0) at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime.lambda$discoverComponents$0(ComponentRuntime.java:132) at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime.lambda$discoverComponents$0$ComponentRuntime(Unknown Source:0) at com.google.firebase.components.-$$Lambda$ComponentRuntime$4FqOW9eOQsvFYo-HpMfxCOnPQr0.get(Unknown Source:4) at com.google.firebase.components.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:53) at com.google.firebase.components.AbstractComponentContainer.get(AbstractComponentContainer.java:27) at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime.get(ComponentRuntime.java:45) at com.google.firebase.components.RestrictedComponentContainer.get(RestrictedComponentContainer.java:89) at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingRegistrar.lambda$getComponents$0$FirebaseMessagingRegistrar(com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@22.0.0:7) at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingRegistrar$$Lambda$0.create(Unknown Source:0) at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime.lambda$discoverComponents$0(ComponentRuntime.java:132) at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime.lambda$discoverComponents$0$ComponentRuntime(Unknown Source:0) at com.google.firebase.components.-$$Lambda$ComponentRuntime$4FqOW9eOQsvFYo-HpMfxCOnPQr0.get(Unknown Source:4) at com.google.firebase.components.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:53) at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime.doInitializeEagerComponents(ComponentRuntime.java:291) at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime.initializeEagerComponents(ComponentRuntime.java:281) at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeAllApis(FirebaseApp.java:584) at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(FirebaseApp.java:303) at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(FirebaseApp.java:267) at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(FirebaseApp.java:252) at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(FirebaseInitProvider.java:51) at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:2092) at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:2066) at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(FirebaseInitProvider.java:45) at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:7237) at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6782) at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6693) at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:232) at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2014) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:241) at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7617) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:941) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.datatransport.runtime.dagger.internal.Factory at com.google.android.datatransport.runtime.DaggerTransportRuntimeComponent.builder(DaggerTransportRuntimeComponent.java:70)Â  at com.google.android.datatransport.runtime.TransportRuntime.initialize(TransportRuntime.java:76)Â  at com.google.firebase.datatransport.TransportRegistrar.lambda$getComponents$0(TransportRegistrar.java:37)Â  at com.google.firebase.datatransport.-$$Lambda$TransportRegistrar$cPZPPfWZLxVwhtSgzJNU9TpSidE.create(Unknown Source:0)Â  at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime.lambda$discoverComponents$0(ComponentRuntime.java:132)Â  at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime.lambda$discoverComponents$0$ComponentRuntime(Unknown Source:0)Â  at com.google.firebase.components.-$$Lambda$ComponentRuntime$4FqOW9eOQsvFYo-HpMfxCOnPQr0.get(Unknown Source:4)Â  at com.google.firebase.components.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:53)Â  at com.google.firebase.components.AbstractComponentContainer.get(AbstractComponentContainer.java:27)Â  at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime.get(ComponentRuntime.java:45)Â  at com.google.firebase.components.RestrictedComponentContainer.get(RestrictedComponentContainer.java:89)Â  at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingRegistrar.lambda$getComponents$0$FirebaseMessagingRegistrar(com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@22.0.0:7)Â  at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingRegistrar$$Lambda$0.create(Unknown Source:0)Â  at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime.lambda$discoverComponents$0(ComponentRuntime.java:132)Â  at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime.lambda$discoverComponents$0$ComponentRuntime(Unknown Source:0)Â  at com.google.firebase.components.-$$Lambda$ComponentRuntime$4FqOW9eOQsvFYo-HpMfxCOnPQr0.get(Unknown Source:4)Â  at com.google.firebase.components.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:53)Â  at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime.doInitializeEagerComponents(ComponentRuntime.java:291)Â  at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime.initializeEagerComponents(ComponentRuntime.java:281)Â  at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeAllApis(FirebaseApp.java:584)Â  at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(FirebaseApp.java:303)Â  at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(FirebaseApp.java:267)Â  at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(FirebaseApp.java:252)Â  at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(FirebaseInitProvider.java:51)Â  at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:2092)Â  at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:2066)Â  at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(FirebaseInitProvider.java:45)Â  at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:7237)Â  at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6782)Â  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6693)Â  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:232)Â  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2014)Â  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)Â  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:241)Â  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7617)Â  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)Â  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)Â  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:941)Â 2021-11-09 14:09:39.279 4694-12739/? W/ActivityTaskManager: Force finishing activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install **Xamarin.Google.Dagger** from the Nuget package manager